# Images are not loaded from certain sites

Tags: c#

I wrote a small program for downloading images by URL. And everything seems to work, but there are a couple of sites from which the image is loaded in 0 bytes and just does not open. Does anyone know why this is happening? Can there be any error in the code?

```
        WebClient client;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = textBox2.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    string count1 = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles().Length.ToString();
                    int count = Convert.ToInt32(count1);
                    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                    if (Path.GetExtension(uri.AbsolutePath) == "")
                    {
                        string one = Path.GetExtension(uri.AbsolutePath) + ".jpeg";
                        string fileName = (count + 1) + one;
                        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + @"\" + fileName);
                    } else
                    {
                        string one = Path.GetExtension(uri.AbsolutePath);
                        string fileName = (count + 1) + one;
                        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + @"\" + fileName);
                    }
                });
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the file download has completed successfully?  You're calling `DownloadFileAsync()` but don't appear to be subscribed to the [`DownloadFileCompleted` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted), which is how it communicates back the result of the download operation.  Also, since you're calling an `*Async` `WebClient` method you probably don't need the `Thread`, and you can simplify your file count to `int count = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).GetFiles().Length;`

Comment: @BACON Well, the program works correctly with practically all sites except a few.

Comment: Yes, but obviously there's something different happening with those few.  If there's an error during downloading you won't know about it with this code.  I think it'd be a good idea to rule that out.

Comment: There are tons of "how to scrape web sites" questions. Please familiarize yourself with them and when you done with research [edit] question to clarify what prevents downloading from those sites (like "user-agent" mismatch) so someone can help to mimic working requests.